# What causes the 'Cannot unregister UpdatePanel' error?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I've got a UserControl that contains an UpdatePanel.  When I put that on a page, it throws the following error:

> Cannot unregister UpdatePanel with ID
>   'ReviewContentUpdatePanel' since it
>   was not registered with the
>   ScriptManager. This might occur if the
>   UpdatePanel was removed from the
>   control tree and later added again,
>   which is not supported. Parameter
>   name: updatePanel

`ReviewContentUpdatePanel` is the name of the update panel & it's not being removed or added in code, it exists in the aspx page and isn't removed.  Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: Have you got a ScriptManager on the page containing the UserControl?

Comment: yep, and a scriptproxy on the usercontrol

Comment: Can you post code?  Most of the references to this error deal with adding  updatepanels/controls dynamically.  Is the user control being added dynamically?

Comment: No it's not, it's just sitting on the control in code in front

Comment: There's no code that interacts with the updatepanel

Comment: Is the output of the UserControl cached?

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't change the error if I turn off output caching

Answer (score 5):

This error occurs when the Controls collection in which the UpdatePanel is resided is cleared using the [Clear method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlcollection.clear.aspx), or when the specific UpdatePanel is removed using the [Remove method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlcollection.remove.aspx).

A trigger for these methods could be the implementation of the [CreateChildControls method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.createchildcontrols.aspx) for the control contains the UpdatePanel. Usually, you call Controls.Clear() in the top of this method, to start with a clean slate if this method is called repeatedly.

Answer (score 4):

Are you moving controls about in code? If so take a look [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2006/11/16/adding-removing-updatepanels-dynamicaly-from-a-page.aspx) and see if this solves your problem.

Comment: I'm not moving *anything* around in code, nothing is interacting with the update panel or its containg usercontrol in code

Comment: Can you post some sample code (if it is not sensitive that is)

Comment: Ignore that - i've just seen the comments in the other post.
New to SO!

Answer (score 3):

I had this happen once before. To fix it, I just deleted it and then re-created it and the problem went away.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps someone else as it drove me nuts.  After finding various tidbits of info here and there on here and elsewhere, I finally came up with the following fix.  Note, I am not dynamically creating this update panel here or anywhere else and most info out there was related to creating this control dynamically, which I was not.

I was using an update panel inside a web user control used on a page inherited by a master page with the script manager.  I don't know if this combo was what was causing it, but this is how I fixed it (inside the web user control where the update panel is utilized):

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
    MethodInfo m = (
    from methods in typeof(ScriptManager).GetMethods(
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance
        )
    where methods.Name.Equals("System.Web.UI.IScriptManagerInternal.RegisterUpdatePanel")
    select methods).First<MethodInfo>();

    m.Invoke(sm, new object[] { updatePanel });
    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

Comment: I needed to remove and re-add a user control containing an update panel in some cases.  I re-jiggered my code to call something like this method only after re-adding the user control, and it worked.  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

In your markup, make sure you've specified an ID for both UpdatePanels and for every runat="server" control in their parent hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including a ScriptManagerProxy in the user control?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the scriptproxy of UserControl. In this case you only have a ScriptManager on your page.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a long shot, but I've had experiences with the AJAX extensions, specifically with the update panel, in which errors thrown by child controls were manifesting themselves as a different error thrown by the update panel.  I did see a reference to this specific error being thrown due to an error in a child control:

http://msmvps.com/blogs/shareblog/archive/2009/03/11/cannot-unregister-updatepanel-with-id-since-it-was-not-registered-with-the-scriptmanager-and-moss.aspx

Not sure if this is the case for you or not, but I've spent many hours chasing down the wrong errors because of this.