# Error: Cannot unregister UpdatePanel with ID 'UpdatePanel1'

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

UPDATED
I am getting the error: 
Cannot unregister UpdatePanel with ID 'UpdatePanel1' since it was not registered with the ScriptManager. This might occur if the UpdatePanel was removed from the control tree and later added again, which is not supported.
Parameter name: updatePanel

The only panel I have on the page is not dynamic and is coded on the .aspx page.

The problem is I do not have an UpdatePanel on my page with ID of "UpdatePanel1".

Also when I run in Chrome it works fine, but when I run in IE9 I get this error.

I have not edited this page in some time and it was working before.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:  I found out that on the previous page I have UpdatePanel1 and UpdatePanel2.  on the previous page I am doing a server.transfer to the new page.

When debugging It transfers to new page, then somehow goes BACK to the original page and will trigger the unload events (if I place them in the page on the unload events for the UpdatePanels.

This makes the error go away for cannot unregister panel, but then the next page does not load ANYTHING, it appears blank.  I step through it all and it looks like it should load everything, but I am not sure why it is not displaying anything on the page, if I view source it does not have much.

NOTE:  I am also using master pages and the script manager is in the master page.

Comment: Not sure if help, but I found a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238915/what-causes-the-cannot-unregister-updatepanel-error

Comment: Possible solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9148565/122005

Comment: I saw the first one from Martin.

And I have seen the second one as well, what is weird is that I dont have a control called "UpdateControl1" on the page at all, and it works fine in Chrome (just not in IE)

Comment: I tried the second one from chridam, even though I dont have an updatepane with ID = "UpdatePane1", I put it on the only panel I had but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution (well found cause of problem)

For whatever reason my onsbumit form return javascript validation was the problem.

I just had to change the onclientclick to return validate vs what I had if(validate = false) return false).

For WHATEVER reason that was causing all my problems.

Comment: hi, where i can edit my code, and how can i follow your answer, i got the same error.. can you please elaborate your answer? thanks