# updatePanel in Griview ItemTemplate has issue on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, updatepanel, postback

In my `gridItemTemplate` , I have Update panel and check box ,

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upChkOption">
       <ContentTemplate>   
           <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkOption" AutoPostBack="true"   
            OnCheckedChanged="chkOption_CheckChanged">                                
       </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</ItemTemplate>
```

First time running has no error , but after `postback` , I got this error

```
Cannot unregister UpdatePanel with ID 'upChkOption' since it was not registered with   
the ScriptManager. This might occur if the UpdatePanel was removed from the control  
tree and later added again, which is not supported. Parameter name: updatePanel
```

How can I solve it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238915/what-causes-the-cannot-unregister-updatepanel-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `UpdatePanel_Unload` to the `OnUnload` event of the `UpdatePanel`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upChkOption" runat="server" OnUnload="UpdatePanel_Unload">
```

Add this in code behind

```
protected void UpdatePanel_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e) 
      {
 MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(ScriptManager).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(i => i.Name.Equals("System.Web.UI.IScriptManagerInternal.RegisterUpdatePanel")).First();
  methodInfo.Invoke(ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page),
            new object[] { sender as UpdatePanel });
    }
```

[Adding/removing UpdatePanels dynamicaly from a page](http://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2006/11/16/adding-removing-updatepanels-dynamicaly-from-a-page.aspx)

[cannot-unregister-updatepanel-since-it-was-not-registered-with-the-scriptmanager-error](http://www.kruegerwebdesign.com/blog/cannot-unregister-updatepanel-since-it-was-not-registered-with-the-scriptmanager-error)

Answer (score 1):

According to Ali Dehghan Tarzeh' answer:

> you should add the UpdatePanel_Unload to the OnUnload event of the
>   UpdatePanel:
>
> ```
> <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" OnUnload="UpdatePanel_Unload">
> ```

**In Code behind :**

```
protected void UpdatePanel_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(ScriptManager).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Where(i => i.Name.Equals("System.Web.UI.IScriptManagerInternal.RegisterUpdatePanel")).First();
    methodInfo.Invoke(ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page),
        new object[] { sender as UpdatePanel });
}
```